# How to properly disconnect signal ready read from QNetworkreply

Tags: qt, signals, slot

following issue abot my code. For unserstanding reason I connect to an event stream which publish every minute the actual status of a device under the url of : "urldevice"/event-stream. I connect a slot to the signal "readyread" and will disconnect. But still I am calling the disconnect function I recieve information in the cnnected slot.

Here is my code

```
QNetworkRequest request(_url + "events");
request.setRawHeader("Accept", "text/event-stream");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::UserAgentHeader, "Plugin");
if (_token != "") {
    request.setRawHeader("accept", "*/*");
    QString token = "Bearer " + _token;
    request.setRawHeader("Authorization", token.toUtf8());
}
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);
request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControlAttribute,
                     QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork);  // Events shouldn't be cached

_sseReply = _sseNetworkManager->get(request);
QObject::connect(_sseReply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &streamReceived);



void streamReceived() {
    if (_sseReply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qCDebug(m_logCategory) << "streamrecieved";
   } else {
        qCDebug(m_logCategory) << "disconnect";
   }
}

void disconnect() {
if (_sseReply->isRunning()) {
        _sseReply->abort();
        _sseReply->close();
        _sseNetworkManager->disconnect(_sseReply,&QNetworkReply::readyRead,this,&streamReceived);
        _sseNetworkManager->disconnect();
        _sseReply->disconnect();
        qCDebug(m_logCategory) << "isrunnung";
    }
    _flagStandby = true;
    QObject::disconnect(_sseReply, &QNetworkReply::readyRead, this, &streamReceived);
}
```

after caling disconnect() I see all the time

```
disconnect
```

in my log

How do I properly disconnect from the signal???

Comment: Does `this` refer to the same object in both the `QObject::connect `and `QObject::disconnect` calls?  What is the value returned by `QObject::disconnect`?

Comment: It returns true and the address of both is the same

Comment: I solved it by using         _sseNetworkManager->clearConnectionCache();